# constructor inside constructor - bad practice?

Tags: javascript

I'm exploring some code and I saw the practice of embedding one constructor function into another used many times:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
function contact_duplicates_manager(global_objects)
{
    this.field_processors =
    {
        "Phone1Number": new phone_processor(),
        "Phone2Number": new phone_processor(),
        "Phone3Number": new phone_processor()
    }
    //...here some other code

    /**
     * @constructor
     */
    function phone_processor()
    {
        //...here some other code

        function clear_phone(phone)
        {
            //...here some code
        }
        this.is_equals = function (value1, value2) 
        {
            return is_equals(clear_phone(value1), clear_phone(value2));
        }
    }
}

//... later in the code
var valid = this.field_processors[fld_name]["is_equals"](native_value, custom_value)
```

Do you think `phone_processor` constructor function should be outside `contact_duplicates_manager`?

Comment: At first I would write it in readable format (Java style).

Comment: How is `phone_processor()` actually used?

Comment: This is merely a `function` within a `function`, and there's nothing *wrong* with it. Encapsulating code that is only used in the parent function is in my opinion a good practice.

Comment: @nnnnnn, I've updated the example to demonstrate how it's used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you think `phone_processor` function constructor should be outside `contact_duplicates_manager`?

Yes. While being valid and working, it's not efficient and possibly unreadable. With the nesting, every `contact_duplicates_manager` instance has `phone_processor`s with different constructors and inheriting from a different prototype object. This might be necessary for constructor factories or similar patterns, but those are very rare and I doubt you need it here.

My rules of thumb:

> - Move every function that does not need access to any local closure variable to a higher scope.
> - If you don't want it to be public in there, use an intermediate scope of an [IEFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).
> - If you need a constructor inside the scope of a multiple-times-executed function, try to share the prototype object among the constructors, and do not leak a local constructor.

An example for the last rule:

```
function Item(…) {…}
function Store {
    var that = this;
    this.items = [];
    this.addItem = function(…) {
        that.items.push(new LocalItem(…));
    };
    function LocalItem(…) {
        Item.call(this, …);
        this.store = that;
    }
    LocalItem.prototype = Item.prototype;
}
```

You don't necessarily need the global `Item` function which you call inheritance-like, sometimes a single global `proto` object which you can assign to `LocalConstructor.prototype` is enough.