# Javascript Object constructor as a method of another object

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

I have this object:

```
var x = function(){

    var returnObj = {

        constructor:function(ieps){

            this.jow = ieps

        }

    }

    returnObj.constructor.prototype.build = function(){

        alert(this.jow)

    }

    return returnObj

}
```

**That i would like to call with this:**

```
var jow = new x.constructor("ieps")
jow.build()
```

So i try to get the build() to execute the alert but i get a x.build() is undefined.

Any ideas?

thx,

Comment: I guess you want to **call** `x`: `new (x().constructor)('foo')`. You can only access the return value of the function if you call the function.

Comment: You're trying to use a module pattern, but neglected to invoke the outer function. Just add `()` to the end of that function.

Comment: Notice that you probably [shouldn't create constructors inside a function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20784304/1048572) (except that function is supposed to be used as a singleton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is a function that returns the object, which has a constructor as property. You must first call the function. Secondly, you can't go with `new x().constructor("ieps")` since that gets parsed as `(new x()).constructor("ieps")` but you actually need `new (x().constructor)("ieps")`. Finally, we arrive at:

```
var jow = new (x().constructor)("ieps")
jow.build()
```

Comment: var jow = new x().constructor("ieps") was actually enough (so no extra explicit expression forcing needed, the extra ()