# javascript: how to call a function in both method and constructor contexts simultaneously?

Tags: javascript

I want to say:

```
 var b = new a.B();
```

where `a` is an object. I want the method `B` to be able to refer to the calling object `a` and to the newly created object `b`.

Normally, first reference is achieved via method context and second - via constructor context. Both contexts bind referenced objects to `this` keyword.

But how do I refer to both of them during a single call to `B`?

**USE CASE:**

Suppose, that I've written a library that allows user to easily insert my widget inside his web-page. Upon load my library exports a single name to the global namespace: `Toolbar`, which is a constructor that creates my widget within user's web-page element, called `parent_dom_element`:

```
var toolbar1 = new Toolbar(parent_dom_element);
```

Now, within my widget, corresponding to `toolbar1` object, user can create sub-widgets like this:

```
var comment = new toolbar1.Comment();
```

I want the constructor function `Comment` to be able to refer to the `toolbar1` object and to act as a constructor at the same time like this:

```
Toolbar.prototype.Comment = function (toolbar, ){
    this.attr1 = toolbar.attr1;
};
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You can do `new a().B()`, but `b` variable will be set to whatever `.B` returns. Unless you return the object itself on `.B`, you will lose reference to the newly constructed `a`. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Bob can you elaborate your question. Please make me clear what you expect ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Organize prototype javascript while perserving object reference and inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15884096/1048572), see also [constructor inside constructor - bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20784304/1048572)

Comment: @pramod I've added an example for my question. I hope, it is concise and clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a var inside Toolbar context pointing to 'this' and define the Comment constructor inside the Toolbar constructor. This way, the Comment contructor will get access to the 'toolbar' variable.

```
var Toolbar = function () {
    var toolbar = this;  // toolbar = Toolbar instance
    this.attr1 = "";     // this = Toolbar instance

    this.Comment = function () {
        this.attr1 = toolbar.attr1;  // this = Comment instance;
    };
};

var toolbar1 = new Toolbar();
var comment = new toolbar1.Comment();
```

Comment: If you're going to use this pattern, have a look at [constructor inside constructor - bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20784304/1048572)