# Subclass of a Subclass?

Tags: javascript

I've been writing a game engine, and I wanted to re-organize my code to make it more modular. Currently, I have a main function called `Isometric` that accepts the canvas to draw.

```
var iso = new Isometric('canvas');
```

So far so good. Next, I had `.newMap()` to create a new map.

```
var map = iso.newMap(10,1,10); // Creates 10x1x10 map
```

However, I want to change that since there might be some confusion with the .map property (*since this returns an array called map*).

I wanted the syntax to look like this:

```
iso.Map.create(10,1,10);
```

So I tried something like this:

```
function Isometric(id) {
    this.Map = function() {
        this.create = function() {
        }
    }
}
```

But when I went to access it, I realized that the second level of `this` still refers to the same first level this. So, I can't create a sub-class of the Map object.

I've looked at a few different methods, but none of them had clear examples and I couldn't get them to work.

Among them, I'm aware that you can use `prototype`, and `Object.create()` but I've not gotten much success.

How can I do this?

The other solution I have is to do something like this:

```
function Isometric('id') {
    this.Map = {
        'create': function() { },
        'load': function() {}
    }
}
```

and then access it like

```
iso.Map['create'];
```

but I don't like that at all. Any clean methods of doing it?

My main interest is an example with the third-level method ..create() inside .map. If you could provide me with documentation related to my question that I have not yet found, that would be nice. But even mozilla docs didn't seem to help.

Comment: I can't give you a clear answer, but I can say that prototype is what you should be looking into.

Comment: *"I realized that the second level of 'this' still refers to the same first level this"* most certainly not. Every function has it's "own" this. Calling `iso.Map.create(10,1,10);` doesn't actually work because functions don't have a `create` method. *"and then access it like ...."* There is nothing that prevents you from using dot notation in that case: `iso.Map.create;`

Comment: Thank you, I'll continue to look into .prototype. It's just the set up I'm concerned with. Do I just create all the functions as a list of functions?
function Isometric() { }
function Map() {}
function Create() {}

and then use prototype and all that to connect them somehow? Doesn't seem right.

Comment: Felix, I'm  the one creating the 'create' method though. Edit: I'll try that once more but that didn't do the trick the first time I did it.

Comment: If you just set `this.Map = {...}` you can still do `iso.map.create(...)` btw.

Comment: @Josh: True, but in your first attempt, `this.Map = function() { this.create = function() { } }`, `Map` is a function and functions don't have a `create` method. Just like you cannot call `Isometric.Map`, because `Map` is a property of an *instance* of `Isometric`, `create` would be a property of an instance of `iso.Map` if you called it as `new iso.Map()`.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbx2aariwvcvfwb/Screenshot%202015-02-05%2015.54.35.png?dl=0
Here's what happens when I try to access it as mentioned.

Then how do I make it work, Felix? .-. I'm confused.

Comment: You'll want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/16502467/1048572 and especially [constructor inside constructor - bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20784304/1048572)

Comment: @Josh: WTH?! Please link to jsfiddle itself, instead of making a screenshot and storing that at dropbox!

Comment: @Bergi I did that just to show the error message :P Plus I haven't saved the fiddle.

Comment: @Josh: Oh, it would have been clear enough to us if you just pasted the error message in your comment :-) Regardless, Felix already told you: `var map = new iso.Map(); map.create()`

Comment: Is something like this what you're looking for?  http://jsfiddle.net/h1e819La/

Comment: @istos I haven't gotten the chance to look through it completely, but it looks exactly like what I had hoped for. Post that as an answer and I'll mark that as the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @bergi for clearing up what felix meant. I can't tag felix again, but I'll say thank you to him too in here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the appropriate thing to do here is to namespace your **Map** constructor under the **Isometric** constructor. Here is how you could go about it.

```
function Isometric(id) {
  this.id = id;
}

Isometric.prototype = {
  constructor: Isometric,

  test: function() {
    return "I'm an instance of Isometric.";
  }
};
```

Here we do the namespacing and add a `create()` helper method to the Map constructor to create its instances.

```
Isometric.Map = function Map(x, y, z) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.z = z;
}

Isometric.Map.prototype = {
  constructor: Isometric.Map,

  test: function() {
    return "I'm an instance of Isometric.Map.";
  }
};

// Helper method to create `Map` instances
Isometric.Map.create = function create(x, y, z) {
  return new Isometric.Map(x, y, z);
};
```

**Usage**:

```
var iso = new Isometric('id123');
var map = new Isometric.Map(0, 7, 99);
var map2 = Isometric.Map.create(1, 2, 3);

iso.test(); //=> "I'm an instance of Isometric."
map.test(); //=> "I'm an instance of Isometric.Map."
map2.test(); //=> "I'm an instance of Isometric.Map."
```

### Namespaces

It's important to note that the namespacing we just did prevents collisions with the new `Map` class in ES6 (*new JS version*) - more about ES6 Maps here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map.

With that said, it's always important to namespace your code under one main object (*you could call it `app`*) and only make that namespace available globally.

In your case you could do something like the following example:

```
;(function(win) {
  // Isometric
  function Isometric(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  Isometric.prototype = {
    constructor: Isometric,

    test: function() {
      return "I'm an instance of Isometric.";
    }
  };


  // Map
  function Map(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }

  Map.prototype = {
    constructor: Map,

    test: function() {
      return "I'm an instance of Isometric.Map.";
    }
  };

  // Helper method to create `Map` instances
  Map.create = function create(x, y, z) {
    return new Map(x, y, z);
  };


  // Namespace Map under Isometric
  Isometric.Map = Map;


  // Expose globally
  // --------------------
  win.app = {
    Isometric: Isometric
  };
}(this));
```

**Example:**

```
var nativeMap = new Map();
nativeMap.set('name', 'joe'); //=> {"name" => "joe"}

var myMap = new app.Isometric.Map(33, 7, 99);
myMap.test(); //=> "I'm an instance of Isometric.Map."

// Native map wasn't affected (good)
nativeMap.test(); //=> TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

I will leave the other answer as accepted because it was more detailed and even told me about my code possibly becoming deprecated as is.

That being said, I want to re-iterate Felix King's solution. I will figure a way of combining both ideas (using namespaces and using Felixs) but here's what the partial solution was.

```
function Isometric(id) {
    this.Map = function() {
        this.create = function() {
            return 5;
        };
    };
}
```

That was the set up I had. 5 is just an arbitrary value.

```
 var iso = new Isometric(); // New instance of Isometric()
 var mapping = new iso.Map(); // Access to Iso's mapping functions
 var map = mapping.create(); // Should return a map array 

 console.log(map); // Prints 5
```

For anyone following along on this, if you want to see how I end up implementing it, then see my Github project: https://github.com/joshlalonde/IsometricJS

I'll play around with the code in sometime this weekend.

Again, thanks for your help everyone! Good luck to anyone trying to do something similar.